# Why to use strings.xml?

Tags: android

Could anyone please explain why having hard-coded strings is so bad?
What issues should I expect if I hardcode strings?
Why having a separate string xml file solves those issues?

Creating new elements in strings.xml is such a time consuming activity.

Comment: not only Localization, Centralization is also one of the factor.

Comment: [Android - Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) will explain you Better..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When adding your strings to `strings.xml`, you can easily translate your whole app into other languages.

So in the folder `values` you would have `strings.xml` with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
```

In `values-fr` a `strings.xml` with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>
```

This saves you a ***lot*** of work instead of doing this the hardcoded way: Android automatically selects the correct language based on user preferences, and you don't have to worry about selecting and displaying this language.

Please also read [Localization | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 14):

Plus, suppose you have a string, let it be a title for example, that is repeated in every activity of your app. Now suppose after awhile, you decide to change that title.

Using `strings.xml` you will need to change it in a single place, while hard-coded values will need to be changed in every activity.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute (not the name of the XML file). So, you can combine string resources with other simple resources in the one XML file, under one `<resources>` element.