# Differnece between assigning values directly and and from sources

Tags: android, android-xml

Kindly look at following two codes.

1) `android:text="1"`

2) `android:text="@string/Value"`

I am new on Android, I just want to know which method is more preferable, are there any problems created in future of application?

Answer (score 1):

Second one`android:text="@string/Value"` is more preferable because:

1. If you want to translate your app into another language, you just
   need this one file which has all the strings that your app uses.
2. If you have to make any changes to any string, you know by default
   where to look for(All at one place).
3. Re-use of strings is possible using this way.

Have a look at answers at following questions:

- [Why to use strings.xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794944/why-to-use-strings-xml-in-android)
- [Benefit of Declaring String as Resource in strings.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310515/benefit-of-declaring-string-as-resource-in-strings-xml-file)
- [Defining Strings in res/values/string.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475599/defining-strings-in-res-values-string-xml)

You'll get your answer. Hope this helps.